# Using AsynTask to show progress bar while attempting to SSH to Server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

First of all,  i have to state that i am new to Java in general & Android. I do however have the basics, or at least getting there.

The Purpose of my Application: At the company, we have a Remote server that we SSH to, and do some work. At some times, the server is unreachable and therefore disrupts our work.

My application is suppose to do the following:

1- Using Jsch, i SSH to the server, if there is a response, then, i will attempt again in 15 minutes, if there is no response, i want to notify.

i have successfully done the above in non android version of Java, and was able to do it in Android version, however on the main thread, thus  i cannot update anything on the UI. In essence the Progress Bar..
In the regular version, the UI freezes, and in the AsyncTask version provided below. i get an exception as soon as i hit the button

Below is the code i am using, to be honest, i read all over that the best solution is AsyncTask, but since i am new to that, i am not sure were my wrong is. I honestly assume its may be in the AsyncTask and AsyncTask  .

I am not sure what to use there...
Below is my code, hopefully someone can point out my mistake.

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;

public class VedasServerMonitorActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    Button button;
    EditText IP;
    EditText UserName;
    EditText Password;
    EditText Port;
    ProgressBar progressBar1;

    String UserStr;
    String PassStr;
    String IPStr;
    int PortInt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        IP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverIp);
        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



                new asyncTaskUpdateProgress().execute();

            }

        });

    }

    public class asyncTaskUpdateProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub







        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UserStr = UserName.getText().toString();
            PassStr = Password.getText().toString();
            IPStr = IP.getText().toString();
            PortInt = Integer.parseInt(Port.getText().toString());

            button.setClickable(true);
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            boolean ok = false;


try {


            SSHTest sshtest = new SSHTest();
            ok = sshtest.sshconnect(UserStr, PassStr, IPStr, PortInt);
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("ERROR HERE", "doInBackground: IOException");}
if (ok) {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     "Connection Susccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
     .show();

} else {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     "Unable to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     notify(getApplicationContext(), true);

}
return null;


        }


        protected void notify(Context context, Boolean on) {
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    getClass().getName());
            Intent intent = new Intent().setComponent(comp);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.warning, "Message",
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            n.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Vedas Server Monitor",
                    "Port Un-rechable", pendingIntent);
            nm.notify(22, n);
        }

    }

}
```

android× 194760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some correction that you need to make in the `doInBackground()`. But before that a small detailing about the `AsyncTask`.

`AsyncTask` is used when you have any non-UI back ground activity to perform. The function `onPreExecute()` is used to show any UI action 
(in most cases its showing of a dialog) before you enter the background thread. The function `doInBackground()` is used to perform the non-ui action (in most cases fetching data from server). While doing the background activity in `doInBackground()` you may wish to show some progress which you do by using `publishProgress()` which will internally call the `onProgressUpdate()` method. On completion of the background activity in `doInBackground()` you return the `result` of the activity, if you have any. After you return from the `doInBackground()` method internally there is call made to the `onPostExecute()` which will receive the `result` you have returned in `doInBackground()` as a parameter. Now `onPostExecute()` will run on a UI thread and most of the UI action like dismissing of dialog which was shown in `onPreExecute()`, displaying the `result` on some UI component etc. happens in this method.

Now to the mistake you are doing in you code:
You are showing a `toast` or a `notification` based on the result of your server data fetch using a function `notify` but you are still in the background non-ui thread. Now this result should ideally be returned and checked in the `onPostExecute()` and based on its value you can show the UI component of `toast`or `notification`.

I hope this explanation helps you in solving your problem.

**EDIT**

In your case since you can send the boolean type result variable `ok` to `onPostExecute()`. For that you need to make the following changes:

in class declaration:

```
public class asyncTaskUpdateProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
if (ok) {

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "Connection Susccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .show();

} else {

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 "Unable to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 notify(getApplicationContext(), true);

}
}
```

and finally in

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        boolean ok = false;


try {


        SSHTest sshtest = new SSHTest();
        ok = sshtest.sshconnect(UserStr, PassStr, IPStr, PortInt);
        }

    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("ERROR HERE", "doInBackground: IOException");}

return ok;

 }
```

Comment: Arun, Thank you, your high level explanation really helps. 
my only problem however is getting down to the code :)... yea am a newbie, but from what you stated regarding the toast and notification, if i comment them for the time being, would it still show the progress bar?

The other issue  i have trouble with is what to pass and how?
example: protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) should  i leave it void ...args0? (this is were i also get lost

Comment: While extending a AsyncTask you specify the 3 parameters type like `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` where `Params` are the parameter type you send to the `doInBackground()` , `Progress` is parameter type you send to the `onProgressUpdate()` and `Result` is for the `onPreExecute()`.

Comment: Ill try that and get back with results. Thanks for the support. Very helpful and clear, i now understand the AsyncTask<params, progress, result> thanks to u

Comment: Getting closer, only issue with protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { ...........return ok; which is an invalid return type.

Comment: ok, i changed the  Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
to  Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

However i got an exception having to do with handlers, pasted below
06-24 22:08:29.717: WARN/System.err(13570): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
com.example.myapp.VedasServerMonitorActivity$asyncTaskUpdateProgress...........................

Comment: Arun, i got it working

Here the changes done.

I had to change the protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){ if (ok) {

to a result onPostExecute(Boolean result){ if (result) { and i also removed the SSHTest sshtest = new SSHTest(); from the protectedBoolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {` to global variable, it all works fine, now all i have to do is put off the progress bar when the process is finished, whether connected or not.

Thank you for your support was tremendous

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
in your `protected void onPreExecute()`
 need to add

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        //reset progress bar status
        progressBarStatus = 0;
```

then

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {  
    progressBarStatus= progressBarStatus + x; // x means any value
       progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);

    }
```

after that you need to finish your progressBar in `onPostExecute()`. like

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressBar.dismiss();
}
```