# Android: Blocking RPC with progress dialog

Tags: android, multithreading, rpc

I have an Android App that uses an RPC mechanism to set/get information to/from a server. I call the RPCs from whithin the main thread (blocking) and I want them to be blocking. However, sometimes a call can last for some seconds and I'd like to display an indeterminate progress dialog after some specified time (e.g. 1 second).

I tried to spawn a new thread that makes the call and the main thread waits in a loop (with sleeps) until the call has been finished. Inside this loope I show the progress dialog but this is not working.

Is it possible to show and update the progress dialog inside another Thread or does anybody know a better solution that allows me to use blocking calls?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AsyncTask`. It is an android mechanism which is used to make such network calls. Get the brief detailing of `AsyncTask` here:

[Using AsynTask to show progress bar while attempting to SSH to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175272/using-asyntask-to-show-progress-bar-while-attempting-to-ssh-to-server/11175715#comment14675001_11175715)

Using a `AsyncTask` you can block the user from proceeding ahead. You have to show a `progress dialog` in the `onPreExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`. All your network related activities will take place in `doInBackground()`. After the background action is completed there will be a call to `onPostExecute()` where the `progress dialog` will be dismissed.

`AsyncTask` is a asynchronous call because you have 2 threads working simultaneously, one is the UI thread on which you are showing your progress dialog and the other is the non-ui background thread which is fetching your data from the server.

Hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do both, make the main thread wait in a loop and show a progress dialog, at the same time. Either the main thread waits or shows the dialog.

Why do you want to block the main thread? Communication over the internet should always be done in a background thread because you never know how long it will take to complete. Do that stuff in `AsyncTask` and show the progress dialog in main.

Comment: I want to block the main thread because I have no benefit in my App if the calls are done asynchronous (the user has to wait anyway before he can proceed) and the asynchronous approach makes the program logic much more complicated.

Comment: Its not that complex. Its a part of almost every app nowadays as most apps use network. let the user wait see a progress dialog while you fetch data in an AsyncTask in the background..

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that seems to work (at least I havent noticed any problems yet). I know the proper way would be to use somethn like AsyncTask but in my case I have no benefit from it and it complicates the program logic.

To update the UI within a new thread:

```
    new Thread() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Looper.prepare();
            ... do UI stuff here
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();
```